# Grafica pastel en php y js

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql

Estoy tratando de sacar una grafica de pastel la cual me ayude a saber lo siguiente:

1. Cuanto fue el numero maximo de ANSERED y cuando fue el numero de NO ANSWERED
2. Saber la extencion de la cual se tomaron esos reguistros por decir en mi columna SRC hay tengo los nombres

Pero me da solo 2 como resultado muestro el ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi codigo es el siguiente:

**getData.php**

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
ini_set('display_startup_errors', '1');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

// MySQL database link code
include ('configuracion.php'); //Fetch productos data
$sql = "SELECT src, COUNT(*) AS RecuentoFilas
FROM cdr WHERE disposition like '%ANSWERED%' 
GROUP BY calldate 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
ORDER BY calldate";

$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql) or die("Error in Selecting " . mysqli_error($link));
//create an array
$array = array();
$i = 0;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $src = $row['src'];
    $RecuentoFilas = $row['RecuentoFilas'];
    $array['cols'][] = array(
        'type' => 'string'
    );
    $array['rows'][] = array(
        'c' => array(
            array(
                'v' => $src
            ) ,
            array(
                'v' => (int)$RecuentoFilas
            )
        )
    );
}
$data = json_encode($array);
echo $data;

?>
```

**Query:**

```
SELECT disposition, COUNT(*) AS RecuentoFilas
FROM cdr WHERE disposition BETWEEN '%ANSWERED%' and disposition like '%NO ANSWERED%' and calldate LIKE '%2017-08-01%' BETWEEN calldate LIKE '%2018-08-01%'
GROUP BY calldate 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
ORDER BY calldate
```

Mi columna SRC son los nombres de las extenciones de los telefonos y mi columna disposition contiene NO ANSWERED y ANSWERED

Busco algo como lo que puedo graficar en Excel
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

YA ME QUEDO
lo que hice fue de la siguiente consulta tomar los ANSWER
para dar el resultado

```
SELECT  disposition, COUNT(*) Total FROM cdr WHERE disposition LIKE'%ANSWER%'  GROUP BY src HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]